# forced reload of two HTTP resources on same page?

Tags: php, http, caching, resources

I am attempting to figure out a way to force a resource at an identical uri to be requested from the server EACH TIME it is referenced on the same page.

For example: I have a dynamically generated image at the url 'mypage.com/img?u=1'

That uri is the src for 2 img tags on the same webpage. No matter what the content ends up being, the image is loaded once and then reused from the browser cache for each reference on that page.

I have tried experimenting w/ every caching header out there:

```
header("Etag: \"".time().rand(100000,999999).'"');
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()-(60*60*24*1000)) . " GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()-(60*60*24*1000)) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, proxy-revalidate, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

This of course prevents the resource from being cached on subsequent page loads, but does nothing for my problem. Before you say that this is an error of my design and I should just user different URIs, know that in this current case that is not an option, nor is dynamically changing the referenced uri client side after the request.

I have even tried using 302,307, and 303 status headers w/ a location redirect to a new unique resource, to no avail. I am starting to think that this is not a solvable problem due to browser design but any input would be GREATLY appreciated!

****UPDATE****
If I use javascript to write a new image w/ the exact same URI as the ones that the browser is reusing on the initial pageload it IS giving me a dynamic (non-cached) result back. Odd

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the link slightly to have a random number at the end?

So the uri will look like: 
'mypage.com/img?u=1&123456' (where 123456 is a result of rand()*100000)

This would cause the image to be reloaded and not stored in the browser cache during initial page loading

**Edit based on OP clarity**

You could try using the javascript onLoad event to wait until the page is loaded (it the first image is completed) before starting the request on the second image, something along the lines of

```
    <img src=# id=secondImage>

    document.onLoad = "document.getElementById('secondImage').src = 'mypage.com/img?u=1'";
```

**Additional edit**

You could also possible try changing .htaccess file

```
    Header set Cache-Control: "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0"
```

Might not help, but might

Comment: Won't work - one of the requirements is that the URI will remain static across resources and cannot be changed serverside or clientside. I need to figure out a way to prevent the browser from reusing the response with some HTTP method(s)

Comment: To Clarify: So you have a script which puts out different information based on the same URI, yet is being cached by the browser because it is the same URI?

Comment: Yes and no. It is not actually being 'cached'. Every subsequent time the URI is being requested it is delivering new, fresh content (per the headers I am setting, which is how it should work). HOWEVER if I have two of the uri requests on the same page load they don't deliver unique responses because they are being requested synchronously and the browser just uses the same response payload.

Comment: I should also add that the reason I cannot change the uri is because I do not have control of the server that is serving the page that requests resources at my URIs, and many times those pages will support no dynamic scripting language and/or javascript - Hence my requirements for the unique content on each request

Comment: If you have no access to the image server, With the original rand() example, the server should just ignore the extra variables you are supplying

Comment: I have access to what the original uri will be, but then it is getting requested from a site outside of my control. The uri resource is my server though obviously and I control the response. Your javascript answer above would work great on a website, but I cannot rely on javascript as this uri will be called from multiple other areas where JS is not supported (such as html emails)